# CHECK: Let $G=\frac{(\mathbb{Z},+)/12\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}}$. How many elements are there in $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\frac{(\mathbb{Z},+)/12\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}}$. How many elements are there in $G$? Write them down explicitly.
\end{prob}

By the 2nd Isomorphism Theorem, $G=\frac{(\mathbb{Z},+)/12\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}} \cong (\mathbb{Z},+)/3\mathbb{Z}$.

The elements of $G$ are $\{0,1,2\}$ and the operation is addition modulo 3.

The elements $\{1,2\}$ have order 12 and generate the whole group.

Is this correct? It seems to simple.

Comment: Yes, tt follows from the second isomorphism theorem. I don't understand yozur second last line. How can an element in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ have order $12$ ? The order of an element divides the order of a group.

Comment: $1$ is an element of $\Bbb Z$, not an element of $\frac{\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z}{3\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z}$. I think the question wants you to write the elements of $G$ as classes of classes of numbers when it says to write them down explicitely.

Comment: And explicitly, $G= \{  \{   \{k + 3n \}+ 12 \mathbb{Z}  \}_{n=0}^3 \}_{k=0}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying $G\cong\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and so it does indeed have three elements which you rightly say are $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ with addition modulo 3. Since this is a cyclic group, it is generated by one element, namely $1$, which has order three ($2$ also has order three).

I'm not sure where you got that both $1$ and $2$ have order 12 (remember that the order of an element divides the order of a group) but that second-to-last line is not correct. Apart from that, it's right!

Comment: I am sorry it is a typo. It should say 3 not 12. Thank you